# Using advertising ID with admob

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

**Background:**
Starting from version 4.0 of the `Google Play Services`, it supports [Advertising ID](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html). It's a user-specific identifier allowing to target the ads better. I've found a lot of examples of retrieving this ID using the new API. But I could not find even single example of using it with `AdMob`.

**Question:**
How to pass advertising ID to `AdMob` in order to get better fitting ad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

Admob will generate this ID under the covers and pass it as required.

Comment: Makes sense, but in this case I would expect to get much higher click rate (CTR). I have 0.30%-0.50% which in my opinion is very low for well targeted ads

Comment: Actually from my experience a mobile CTR of 0.40% is about normal unless you are generating a large number of requests / day (greater than 300K).

Comment: I am generating much less (about 10K per day). Thanks!

Comment: I hope this answer is correct. Do you have an authoritative source, eg a link to a website you can give here?

Comment: No. But there is no mechanism for passing in a user id. Admob has always handled this under the covers.

Comment: So to use Admob, all we need is to add the Manifest and info.plist lines in order to comply with the new AD_ID policy?